# IBM API Connect not showing API that I just created

Tags: api, apiconnect

I just created an API on APIC, but when I search APIs it doesn't show up in the search.  Any idea why or where I can find the API I just created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching for the product. Then you can search through the product's API's and it should be there.